# Conditional fields serializer Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, view

I have a view like this:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = User.object.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return generics.get_object_or_404(User, id=item)
```

serializer like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city']
```

and urls like this:

```
path('<uuid:pk>', UserDetail.as_view(), name='user_detail')
```

Can I using just one view and one serializer fetch in one case all data (id, fist_name, last_name and city) and in other case just the city by json? Or maybe I have to create for it especially a new view and serializer like this:

```
class UserCity(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = User.object.all()
    serializer_class = UserJustCitySerializer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return generics.get_object_or_404(User, id=item)
```

and

```
class UserJustCitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['city']
```

Comment: can you tell condition on the based of which you want to list data.

Comment: I just need to display on one subpage all user informations and on other subpage just the city

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Which will return the field if the condition is true inside your get_your_conditional_field method.

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    your_conditional_field_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = model_name

    def get_your_conditional_field(self, obj):
        # do your conditional logic here
        # and return appropriate result
        return obj
```